# How to REF a PHP Codeigniter controller function inside of jQuery? (Populate a dropdown menu based on current selection))

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

The issue is how do I `POST` the value of the first dropdown selected to my Codeigniter `controller` using jQuery/AJAX. Here is an example of what I need to do http://css-tricks.com/examples/DynamicDropdown/

```
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
    $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val());
});
```

In the `.load()` I want to be able to pass the value of `#first-choice` to my controller.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#first-choice").change(function() {

var str = '';
   $.ajax({
      url: 'getter.php',
      type:'GET',
     dataType:'json',
     data:'choice='+ $("#first-choice").val(),
    success:function(data){ //you must return your data as id and value for the selectbox
      $.each(data as function(v){
       str+='<option value="'+v.yourid+'">'+v.yourvalue+'</option>';
     });
 $("#second-choice").html(str);
    }

   });
});
```

Comment: I'm not using JSON data. Just an array containing distinct values from a table

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#second-choice").load("getter.php",{choice:$("#first-choice").val()},function(){
  //do something here
});
```

this will POST the additional parameters to the server and a callback that is executed when the server is finished responding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
    $("#second-choice").load("<?php echo site_url('controller-name/method-name'); ?>/" + $("#first-choice").val());
});
```

**NOTE:** I have used forward trailing slash to pass your dropdown value as a parameter to your method but this is not necessary you can also pass using get or post method